# Why would Phoebe have been so intrigued with the wrestler's costumes?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

From Friends: [The One With The Ultimate Fighting Champion](http://home.versatel.nl/friendspic0102/transcripts/html/0324.html)

> **Monica:** *He [Pete] wanted to tell me he’s gonna compete is some ultimate fighting competition thingy ... it's like wrestling ...*
>
> ...
>
> **Phoebe:** [intrigued] *Oh?!*
>
> **Monica:** *Yeah, but without the costumes.*
>
> **Phoebe:** [disappointed] *Oh.*

---

Phoebe was immediately intrigued then disappointed. I know that girls like fashion and costumes, but I think Phoebe was **far too** intrigued by the idea.

Was this a play on the fact that girls (in general) are interested "wrestler's costumes" or a joke that was somehow specific to Phoebe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phoebe has shown a long-standing interest in men in extravagant costumes, notably marrying a professional (gay) ice-dancer.

[image]

And dating a fireman

[image]

Comment: Oh ok, so it is a Pheobe thing!